# QRCodeSignature class does not allow logging statements

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker-errors, qr-code

I have a QRCode Signature class i wish to put logging statements and i am starting with the constructor part as :

```
QRCodeSignature::QRCodeSignature(std::vector<WacomType::PEN>* theSigpoints, int theInterval, int theVersion) : sigpoints(theSigpoints), interval(theInterval), version(theVersion) {
Logging::log(QRCodeSignature::logger, Logging::Entry, QRCodeSignature::CLASSNAME, "QRCodeSignature");
```

I have in QRCodeSignature.cpp the following includes

```
  #include "QRCodeSignature.h"
  #include <iostream>
  #include <cstdlib>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <math.h>
```

In QRCodeSignature.h i have got the following class as QRCodeSignature

```
  a constructor
  a virtual destructor
  private:
  static const std::string CLASSNAME;
  static Logging::Logger* logger;
```

In QRCodeSignature.cpp i have got

```
 const std::string CLASSNAME = "QRCodeSignature";
 Logging::logger* QRCodeSignature::logger = NULL;
```

The error when i build this project[Release]

```
 build/Release/MinGW_1-Windows/QRCodeSignature.o: In function `QRCodeSignature':
 C:\repos\impression\trunk\ProsenseSign/QRCodeSignature.cpp:13: undefined reference to `QRCodeSignature::CLASSNAME'
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 make[2]: *** [dist/Release/MinGW_1-Windows/impression.api] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
 make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
const std::string QRCodeSignature::CLASSNAME = "QRCodeSignature";
```

instead of

```
const std::string CLASSNAME = "QRCodeSignature";
```

since second is not initialization of `static-member` of class.